# How do I switch between images indefinitely in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

(I'm using vanilla JS)
So I want the image to switch every 1 second. However it only switches once and stops.

HTML

```
<img class="pic" id="pic" src=
"images/lightsOff.png">
```

JavaScript

```
function imageChange() {
  document.getElementById("pic").src = 
"images/lightsOn.png";
}

setInterval(imageChange, 1000)
```

Comment: it doesn't "stop" - you just never tell it to revert back to the original

Answer (score 1):

You code just keeps setting the same src over and over again. You would need to check to see what the src is and adjust it.  I would just use a data attribute and flip between the two with interval. No need to keep track of a boolean or check what the image is.

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#flip");
window.setInterval(function () {
  var newSrc = img.dataset.src;
  img.dataset.src = img.src;
  img.src = newSrc;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<img data-src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" id="flip"/>
```

If you want to do it without any JavaScript, you have CSS

```css
.alterImg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: swapimg 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes swapimg {
  0% {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200')
  }
  30% {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200')
  }
  70% {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/200')
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/200')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alterImg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should try this :

```js
let toggle = false;
function imageChange() {
  document.getElementById("pic").src = toggle ? "images/lightsOn.png" : "images/lightsOff.png";
  toggle=!toggle;
}
setInterval(imageChange, 1000)
```

You problem was that you set the image to `lightsOff` each second, but we actually need to toggle the image between `lightsOff` and `lightsOn` each second.